# ofstream trouble, how do i resolve this?

Tags: c++, fstream

I am iterating over a map containing words as keys and to each word there are bunch of numbers assigned stored in `vector<int>` indicating on which line they were found. I am having trouble outputting that information in a .txt file.

After enough words garbage appears in the file and the program crashes.

After some brief testing I found out the error occurs on the obvious place, that is when outputting the final information to a .txt file.

After some googling the only relevant snippet of information was somebody briefly saying one should not use ofstream in loops. I guess it could cause overflow somehow? Something not being flushed maybe?

**So what went wrong and why? How do I resolve this?**

```
//FINAL OUTPUT TO A FILE, CREATING A NEW .txt FILE
ofstream filehandle;
filehandle.open("result.txt",ios::out);

if( filehandle.is_open() )
{
     for(map<string, vector<int> >::const_iterator a = line_num_by_word.begin();a!=line_num_by_word.end();++a)
    {
        filehandle << "The word "  << "\"" << a->first << "\"" <<  " is present on: \n";

        vector<int>::const_iterator int_vec_c_it = a->second.begin();

        while( int_vec_c_it != a->second.end() )
        {
            vector<int>::const_iterator in_front_of_it = int_vec_c_it+1;
            //count the number of times
            int counter = 1;
            while( *(int_vec_c_it)==*(in_front_of_it) )
            {
                ++counter;
                ++in_front_of_it;
            }
            filehandle << " line " << *(int_vec_c_it) << "-" << counter << " times ";

            int_vec_c_it = in_front_of_it;
        }
        filehandle << "\n";
    }
}else cout << "no output" <<endl;
```

Comment: Dereferencing a one-past-the-end iterator is undefined behaviour and that's exactly what you're doing with `in_front_of_it`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a->second() is one before end(), it_front_of_it is end(). Then you dereference it in your while.

```
while( *(int_vec_c_it)==*(in_front_of_it) )
```